# Why the difference between "over the phone" and "on television"?

Tags: articles

My dictionary lists the following sentences as examples, but does not explain why "the" is present in the "phone" sentence, and is not in the "television" sentence.

> (1) I talked to him over the phone.
> (2) I saw him on television.

May I ask where this difference comes from?

Comment: Read this: [Definite article — “on television” vs. “on the radio”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7479/definite-article-on-television-vs-on-the-radio)

Comment: But we do say "the" when it's a definite television, just like we do when it's a definite phone, like if I'm watching *the* TV in our living room, see my brother on it, say so, and my son asks me where, I may very well answer, "I just saw him on *the* television." When referring to TV generally as media, in its noncount noun definition, I'll say, "I saw him *on television*," without "the," just like I would if I saw him *on video*, *on film*, etc., all without "the." "Radio" is what's actually a bit peculiar, though one could say in some situations say, "I heard him *over* radio."

Comment: In the UK at least "I saw that on the television" used to be a common expression with a meaning parallel to "I heard that on the radio", "I saw that at the cinema" or "I saw that at the theatre". That was in the earlier days of television, mostly 1950s and 60s I would say. I can't say why the definite article has been dropped when speaking about television but not about the other media but it does seem to have been.

Comment: American English - "Jim is in the hospital." British English - "Jim is in hospital." Related?

Answer (score 1):

*Over* implies a couple of things:

- almost always: distance
- often: a need to cross or make a connection on the other side of that distance in order to reach a destination or result
- often: the destination/result isn't going to come to you from that distance so you need to actively take action instead of passively waiting

> I walked over the bridge to Sally's house.

> I talked to Sally over the phone (voice crossed the phone network).

When you *see* something, that's often a passive activity (the "active" equivalent is *search* or *look*).

So:

- having something merely come into your eyesight without you doing anything (which is one possible definition of *see*) doesn't work with *over*.
- if there is no "connection" being made on the other side of the television (e.g. usually you can't be "present" on the other side of a TV), then that's another reason why *over* isn't used.

(There is the phrasal variation *see over*, or *oversee*, which is equivalent to "supervise" - not the same meaning as plain *see*.)

Answer (score -1):

Let's change the examples a bit to make the contrast look more obvious:

> (1) *I talked to him **on** the **tele**phone.*
>
> (2) *I saw him on television.*

Firstly, note that omitting *the* in (1) is almost impossible, but that adding *the* in (2) *is* possible, albeit less idiomatic.

> (1) ??*I talked to him on telephone.*
>
> (2) *I saw him on the television.*

I think the reason for the different treatment is that you **can see** the content of the television (e.g., TV programs, commercials, etc.) but you **can't see** the content of the telephone. This visual aspect of the television may have enabled the user to distinguish the content (*television* without any determiner) from the device itself (*the television*), especially as the device became more like just a "screen" with other components much less visible to the user.

Since *television* in (2) is more likely to refer to the content rather than the device, adding no determiner sounds much better. In contrast, (*tele*)*phone* in (1) can only refer to the device, so it cannot be used without any determiner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128794/discussion-on-answer-by-jk2-why-the-difference-between-over-the-phone-and-on).